# Connecting DevExpress XtraReports with PostgreSQL in Visual Studio

Tags: postgresql, dll, connection, devexpress, npgsql

I have DevExpress XtraReports v18.1.6 version and PostgreSQL 4 v3.3. Visual studio 2017 v15.3.3 and Windows 7.

Here is scenario: In my project, I have some reports writen in devexpress v17.2. I could not run those reports, because I could not download exactly that version 17.2, I install new 18.1.6. Then in Visual studio main menu "DevExpress" I click on "Project converter to 18.1.." and that action replace my old dlls v17.2 with new 18.1. After that I could run reports (see it in designer).

But problem is with databse connection. I created connection string with "XpoProvider=Postgres".
Every time when I want to get data in report, or rebuild result shema, or manage queries I get error:
**Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0,...**

I have that reference, exactly that version. Also I tried with new versions of threading.tasks but unsuccessfully.

My version of Npgsql.dll was 2.2.7, I tried with 3.2.5 (read from some devexpres documentations). Also tried with new 4.0.3.

Did anyone have a similar problem?

Comment: Install Npgsql through Nuget.   System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions is a dependency of recent versions of Npgsql, but Nuget will handle all of that for you.  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/

Answer (score 0):

we had the same issue when using the DevExpress (18.1) Report Designer with Visual Studio 2017.

I know this might not be an ideal or the best solution but at least it worked for us:

1. I used ProcMon to determine where it was looking for that specific File, for me it turned out to be *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\hhfnlhs1.kna*
2. I downloaded the NuGet Package for System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions from NuGet (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions/)
3. I unzipped the Package and stored the DLL at that path from step 1
4. I had to active "loadFromRemoteSources" in my machine-config (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dd409252(v=vs.100))
5. I had to put another DLL from NuGet (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/4.5.2) into that folder from step 1

That's it - now I can access the DB again.

Comment: I try this and its not working... I copy System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.4.5.1 and System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.5.0 DLLS and entire folders in that path "..IDE\Extensions" and in "...IDE\Extensions\uhuqfcub.t3o". I set "loadFromRemoteSources" in x64 and x32 in "...v4.0.30319\Config" ... Ist not working for me :( thx for answer